# searching block inside text file

Tags: python, bash

I have a text file which has blocks like

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/name_run_number1:
line1_run_number1_part1
line2_run_number1_part2
line3_run_number1_part3...
```

Each block is separated with a blank line and there is the ":" in the "header" of each one while each block has a unique "number1" after "run_" suffix which is also present in the lines inside the block

What I want to do is for each block, extract the "number1" as shown in the first line and then for the lines below count from 1-20 and give a message if a "partX" line is missing. Any bash or python would be fine

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? An example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: there is no need for negative votes, I just tried to ask for the most generic working example- I already wrote `search for a specific string pattern inside`. so the output could be like `block 1 : found your_string in line1 , line3`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by block..

Comment: this is one block
`dir1/dir2/dir3_number:
line1
line2
line3`

this is another block
`dir1/dir2/dir3_other_number:
line4
line5
line6`

Comment: how block 1 and block 2 looks like. `dir1` actually represent the directory or the text in a file?

Comment: edited initial question

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can write a program to accomplish this requirement.

Try the following:

```
def find_text(text):
    """Find some text inside a file."""
    match_lst = []
    with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
        for line in f.readline():
            if line == text:
                match_lst.append(line)
    return match_lst
```

This will give you a Python list containing all matches.

I would also recommend doing this search using regex if you know exactly the content you are searching for however. This isn't clear in the question.